# Is there a way to reset google colab forms to a default value?

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

I really like the new [colabs forms feature](https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/forms.ipynb) for rapidly changing values and seeing how they effect the output.

When I create a form:

```
lead_mm_per_turn = 1.32 #@param {type:"slider", min:0, max:5, step:0.01}
```

Then change the slider value:
[image: Slider adjusted]

It changes the value in code:

```
lead_mm_per_turn = 2.22 #@param {type:"slider", min:0, max:5, step:0.01}
```

Restarting the runtime retains this value.  Is there a way to reset the form to a default value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how to do what you want specifically, but I've run into a similar problem.

In my case, I added a boolean checkbox, which overrides the values if set to true. Ex:

```
#@title {run: 'auto'}

default = False #@param {type: 'boolean'}
if default:
  MAX_LEN = 69
  temperature = 1.1
  top_p = 0.9
  repetition_penalty = 1.4
else:
  MAX_LEN = 44 #@param {type: 'slider', min:0, max:96, step:1}
  temperature = 0.7 #@param {type:"slider", min:0, max:5, step:0.1}
  top_p = 1.7 #@param {type:"slider", min:0, max:5, step:0.1}
  repetition_penalty = 1.1 #@param {type:"slider", min:0, max:5, step:0.1}

#num_beams = 4 #@param {type: 'slider', min:1, max:100, step:1}
#top_k = 4 #@param {type: 'slider', min:1, max:100, step:1}
```

It's not perfect. It doesn't actually changed the visual sliders, but the values of MAX_LEN / temperature / ... are changed.

Hope this helps!